# How to create WebService from WSDL with multiple services in it?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, cxf

I got trouble while creating Web Service from WSDL with two Services. Its from Eclipse IDE with Apache CXF implementation.

I could able to create Web Service and Client from WSDL when I got one Service in WSDL.

Eclipse is giving only ONE option to create Service Name under WSDL2Java Configuration time.

Please suggest me, how to move on?

Comment: Do you want several `wsdl:sevice` in the WSDL?

Comment: I have already got Two <wsdl:service> s inside WSDL. I would like to generate Client and Server stubs out of that WSDL using Apache CXF. Somehow its giving an Error in Eclipse as "Selection must be WSDL" error is occuring..

Comment: As far as I know you only can generate Client side out of WSDL with wsdl2java and not Server side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove second service, and generate the client, then remove the first service and revert the second service, then generate the client again.

On runtime, you need to pass the service end point

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way I can suggest you is to generate the services by a maven plug-in. This plug-in is also named wsdl2java and works as it should. I also tried some times to create the services from the WSDL in java classes with eclipse but it is not working properly. With the wsdl2java plug-in in maven you can have a deeper control on the process of creating service classes. 
This [Link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) can help you to do it. It will look like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
            <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
                </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

jus as a hinwise: If you are not familiar with maven just give it a try. It is easier than you think! and saves you lots of time.